# The whole div between brackets

Tags: css, border

I have a div containing some text and I want to make the whole text (i.e the whole div) between brackets.

Something like that :

[image: example]

I thought of using border top/bottom/right/left but didn't know how to adjust the top and bottom with that space..

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add your current HTML/CSS to see what you have sofar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `pseudoelement`....

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
}

.border-brackets {
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2em;
  color: white;
  margin: 2em;
  border: 1px solid white;
  position: relative;
}

.border-brackets:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 80%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -1px;
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  margin: auto;
}

.border-brackets p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-brackets">
  <p>some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create one `div` and then use `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements to create left and right borders.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
}
div:before {
  border-right: 0;
}
div:after {
  border-left: 0;
  right: -10px;
  left: auto;
}
span {
  display: block;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, unde?</p>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use pseudo elements:

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
}

.test:after,
.test:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  /* length of top and bottom lines */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: -1;
}

.test:after {
  right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
}

.test:before {
  left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
lots of text and stuff<br>
lots of text and stuff<br>
lots of text and stuff<br>
</div>
```